# Grey Box Showing on Release Apk Version

Tags: android, flutter

In my Flutter app, there is a login page. This login page is working perfectly on the debug apk, but when I tried with the released apk, the login button in this not showing and instead of that there is showing a big grey box.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/Auth/auth_widget.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/config/pallet.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vector_icons/flutter_vector_icons.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/widgets/snackbar.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isSignupScreen = false;

  late String email;
  late String password;
  bool processing = false;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
  bool passwordVisible = false;

  void logIn() async {
    setState(() {
      processing = true;
    });

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

        _formKey.currentState!.reset();

        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/main_screen');
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
          });
          MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(
              _scaffoldKey, 'No User found for that email.');
        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
          });
          MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(
              _scaffoldKey, 'wrong password provided for that user.');
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        processing = false;
      });
      MyMessageHandler.showSnackBar(_scaffoldKey, 'please fill all details');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.backgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 20),
                color: Color(0xFF3b5999).withOpacity(.85),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Welcome to ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            letterSpacing: 2,
                            color: Colors.yellow[700],
                          ),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: 'Graphic Solutions',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.yellow[700],
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'Login to continue',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        letterSpacing: 1,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 200,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                        blurRadius: 15,
                        spreadRadius: 5)
                  ]),
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isSignupScreen = false;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'LOGIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isSignupScreen
                                    ? Palette.textColor1
                                    : Palette.activeColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (!isSignupScreen)
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                height: 2,
                                width: 55,
                                color: Colors.orange,
                              )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isSignupScreen = false;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'SIGN UP',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isSignupScreen
                                    ? Palette.activeColor
                                    : Palette.textColor1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (isSignupScreen)
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                                height: 2,
                                width: 55,
                                color: Colors.orange,
                              )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'please enter your email';
                                } else if (value.isValidEmail() == false) {
                                  return 'invalid email';
                                } else if (value.isValidEmail() == true) {
                                  return null;
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                email = value;
                              },
                              // controller: _emailController,
                              decoration: textFormDecoration.copyWith(
                                labelText: 'Email Address',
                                hintText: 'Enter your Email Address',
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'please enter your password';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  password = value;
                                },
                                obscureText: passwordVisible,
                                decoration: textFormDecoration.copyWith(
                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        passwordVisible
                                            ? Icons.visibility
                                            : Icons.visibility_off,
                                        color: Colors.purple,
                                      )),
                                  labelText: 'Password',
                                  hintText: 'Enter your Password',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            processing == true
                                ? const Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Colors.purple,
                                  ))
                                : PositionedButton(
                                    onPressed: logIn,
                                  ),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PositionedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;
  const PositionedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        top: 455,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: onPressed,
            child: Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.orange[200]!,
                        Colors.red[400]!,
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      )
                    ]),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I'm not understanding why this issue is happening.
In this, you can see `PositionedButton` is the login button,

This button is not showing and instead, there is a big grey box at the bottom.

Comment: The grey box comes because there is a UI  error in the release mode.

Comment: How to fix this

Comment: please add the screenshot of the app where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of UI related problems such as overflow or rendering errors.

In debug mode, even if there are such errors, the app will display the screen. But in release mode, you will see a grey screen.

To fix this, run your app in debug mode.

Then, check the logs.

You will see some errors or warnings related to overflows or rendering issues.

Fix those, and the grey screen will go away.